# Turn off LEDs on case fans?

Tags: fan, case, led, case-mods

I'm thinking of getting LED strips with adjustable colors for my PC. The problem is that I have several case fans, all with bright LEDs on them. I want to turn off these LEDs. What my first idea is is to just cut the wire that goes through the lights, but I'm worried that this might break the fan. Will the fan continue to run if I cut that wire? Is there any other (more elegant) way to turn off the fans? And I don't need to be able to turn them on again, I just need them off.

Comment: The wire is on the part of the fan that spins and has nothing to do with the mechanics that cause the fan to spin.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the wiring the fan should still work, but personally I would just put a switch into the wire then it wouldn't matter and I'd know for sure, plus I could always turn the LED's back on if I wanted.